# headers response without location

Tags: python, json

I need information about location from Network Response. When I send post method I tried print body of response, and i get for example : `{"_id":"12313124", "name":"NameElement", "address":"AddressStreet"}`
I need separate only id, because I need this to my tests (edit and delete). How I can do this ?

My code:

```
r = requests.post(*args)
print(r.response)
print(r.headers)
```

Comment: `r.json()['_id']`

Answer (score 0):

Try `r.response['_id']` if `_id` is what you mean "separate only id".